# Cocos2D complex animations

Tags: iphone, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am in the middle of a process of porting my game from Flash to iOS, using Cocos2D. I have a working version now and I am glad I could count with cocos for this. However, i seem to have stumbled upon a small issue. During the development process, I ask my artists to give me the animations set and i just call them as if they were assets.

I have seen examples of animation usage on Cocos, but I have only seen animations created by code. Furthermore, in my game we use animations that are composed of several parts. For example, a character would have his legs as different images than his body, and the animation would then place said images in accordance to the body and arrange them. Seeing Cocos2D's examples i was hopeful about the grossini animation, but then i saw the spritesheet had the whole frame as one image.

I feel like this is a very oldschool way of animating, as artists are supposed to animate a bit better than i can, mixing several images. Plus, adding some 5 lines of code more just so it can display an animation (we have a lot of em), seems to be sub-optimum.

Is there a tool or examples to guide me on implementing this kinds of complex animations? Am I asking for too much out of cocos or are there more developers/artists on this issue?

Comment: Cocos2d-iphone is quite a new framework (it's still 1.0-rc2) so most of the stuff are still manual. We are yet to have Interface Builder-like drag and drop tools for arranging layers and sprites. Although we are quite lucky to have support for loading TMX (tilemap) files and FNT (bitmap font) files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this tool?

- [Tool - Export timeline animations from Adobe Flash and import as Cocos2d Actions](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/6239)

**EDIT:**

- [[AnimationKit] Framework to manage animations](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/13851)
- [iOS-Animation-Kit](https://github.com/anton-nikan/iOS-Animation-Kit)
- [SWFSheet – create sprite sheets from SWFs](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2939)
- [SWFSheet 1.1 Final](http://www.bit-101.com/blog/?p=2977)

Answer (score 1):

I've been behind a Kickstarter project called Spriter (http://www.brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm) and it seems to give artists a decent tool to animate the way I wanted to. Looking good so far!