# How to Export a Flash tween or timeline animation as cocos2d-x actions?

Tags: flash, animation, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0, ccaction

Is there a way to export Flash tweens so that we can use them in cocos2d-x?

Our goals are to let our artist use flash to create the dialog animations, and then export the matrix animations (not the images). Then we would use the matrix animations to animate our dialog transitions.

As an example, see this Juice Cubes video at around 2:12: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y-e5qJibVcM.

The what we would like to get is just a list of position, rotation, skew, etc over time.

We tried exporting a tween as as3, but the results are pretty complicated, and seem to require knowledge of Flash's different types of tweens.

BTW, I have seen this question asked an various forms, but no answers so far. I would love to know where to find the tool described here: [Cocos2D complex animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6106401/cocos2d-complex-animations)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use those ones.

- [raymondlu/super-animation-samples](https://github.com/raymondlu/super-animation-samples)
- GAF http://gafmedia.com/

super-animation-samples seems to be stopped development, so GAF is more suitable for you.